# Matplotlib How to get the gap and whitespace distance between subplots (axes)

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, graph-visualization

May I know if anyone knows how to print those whitespace distances between subplots (axes)? I have the code that I draw the the two gridmesh, could you help me figure out how to print those parameters for whtie space?
[image]

```
grid_data = np.array([[[-0.1779874 , -0.90335705, -0.31157705,  0.77770067],
        [ 0.93698288,  0.79215241,  0.10155888,  0.96101718],
        [ 0.72994894, -0.83939131,  0.24713443,  0.74839211],
        [ 0.10039462, -0.95778299,  0.43554077,  0.61927077]],

       [[ 0.52294259, -0.0247383 ,  0.23717517, -0.0857769 ],
        [-0.43539246,  0.28503173, -0.39443502, -0.1478289 ],
        [-0.2327904 , -0.08339054,  0.33072907,  0.74634504],
        [-0.524284  , -0.72919194, -0.61543159,  0.17086563]]])
num_cols = 2
num_rows = 1
fig_size_h = 42/32*num_cols
fig_size_v = 14/10*num_rows
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = num_rows, ncols = num_cols, figsize = (fig_size_h, fig_size_v))
for i in range(num_cols):
    c = axes[i].pcolormesh(grid_data[i], cmap = 'RdBu_r', vmin = -1., vmax = 1.)
# Add a color bar
cb_ax = fig.add_axes([0.91, 0.13, 0.01, 0.75])
fig.colorbar(c, cax = cb_ax)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have a feeling about the default whitespace pecs that will be changed automatically by the matplotlib, so I want to know how to literally print those number out in Python.

Comment: E.g. `fig.subplotpars.left` is the value of `left`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you. Do you know how to print the size of the subplot (axes) it self too?

Comment: The axes size `axw` is determined by those parameters. `right-left = axw*(n+(n-1)*wspace)`, similar for the height direction.

Comment: However, note that you get the axes positition directly via `ax.get_position()`; so that might be more helpful for many cases.

Answer (score 0):

all those parameters can be adjusted using this :

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html

defaults are also listed

Comment: what's the size of the subplot itself?

Comment: by the way, do you know what's the code to access those number, like we could literally print those current dimensions out in Python?